# Run the command "Get-Help entityframework failed in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am studying to develop web api by using .NET Core 5.0. At this time I am studying Entity Framework. I have already installed Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework tools in Visual Studio 2019.

However when I run the command

```
Get-Help entityframework
```

in the Package Manager console, I get an error as shown below. Can anyone help resolve this issue?

> Get-Help : Get-Help could not find entityframework in a help file in this session. To download updated help topics type: "Update-Help". To get help online, search for the help topic in the TechNet library at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=107116.
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - Get-Help entityframework
> - 
> - CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Get-Help], HelpNotFoundException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : HelpNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand

Answer (score 3):

if you have installed only Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLServer Package then you are not able to run any entity framework package manager console commands if want to run add-migration or other related commands then you need install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools package also

Answer (score 0):

First install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools with the help of NuGet Package Manager.

Comment: One liner answers are not helpful for users. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer